# G++ failed to compile __attribute__ keyword

Tags: c++, compilation, g++

I tried compiling **attribute** with g++, but failed, gcc will compile successfully.
g++ test.c -o test

Here is the function:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct student{
    int num;
};

static __inline int student_information (struct student *) __attribute__((__unused__));
static __inline int student_information(stu) struct student *stu;
{
    return 0;
}

int main(void)
{
    struct student *stu = (struct student *)malloc(sizeof(struct student));
    student_information(stu);

    return 0;
}
```

Here is the failture message:

```
test.c:9:44: error: ‘student_information’ declared as an ‘inline’ variable
 static __inline int student_information(stu) struct student *stu;
                                            ^
test.c:9:44: error: ‘int student_information’ redeclared as different kind of symbol
test.c:8:21: error: previous declaration of ‘int student_information(student*)’
 static __inline int student_information (struct student *) __attribute__((__unused__));
                     ^
test.c:9:41: error: ‘stu’ was not declared in this scope
 static __inline int student_information(stu) struct student *stu;
                                         ^
test.c:10:1: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘{’ token
 {
 ^
test.c:8:21: warning: inline function ‘int student_information(student*)’ used but never defined [enabled by default]
 static __inline int student_information (struct student *) __attribute__((__unused__));
```

I don't know why this is wrong, but how do I compile **attribute** with g++

Comment: You don't think that `int student_information(stu) struct student *stu;` is wrong? Wow -- this is ancient K&R C declaration format. Ancient as: dinosaurs roamed the Earth when this syntax was used last time. Where did you find such a fossil? And how did that come attached with `__inline` and `__attribute__`? This is like seeing such a dinosaur walking down the street and talking on its I-phone.

Comment: Hi Sam Varshavchik, thank you for your answer.I found this code in the early days of freeBSD. There was an internal code that used this style, and I was very confused when I saw it.

Comment: So we have now proven that a C++ compiler doen't like some C code from the 1970's. Let's just make a note of that, and carry on.

Comment: hi Bop, I use extern "C" to put this code in GCC because GCC compile is ok, but g++ will not compile，I wonder what the reason will be

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because g++ is a C++ compiler and you're giving it invalid C++: it has to reject this code, so it just tells you why and quits. Also, the `__attribute__` keyword is a compiler-specific extension, which in this case could be replaced by [[[maybe_unused]]](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes/maybe_unused). In fact nothing in standard C++ starts with any underscores: such names are reserved for use as custom extensions or implementation details by compiler and standard library implementations.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it should be related to the editor, and the code style is too old, maybe the c++ compiler will not accept.